# Hierarchical org refile support with ivy

Tags: org-mode, ivy

When I enable `ivy-mode` in an org buffer and `C-c C-w` for refile, all headlines are presented as refile targets. So far so good. I relied on the org default setting `(org-outline-path-complete-in-steps 't)` which presents me a hierarchical possibility to complete the refile target.

I have 377 headings in my org files, of which 7 are top level headings (nesting level 1, one star *)

I wonder if there is a method to somehow emulate hierarchical completion with ivy?

What I am looking for is, besides of regex completion / search in ivys completion narrowing, ivy support to "cycle" through the hierarchies of the heading nesting level I am currently at.

Comment: See the discussion here: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/986.

Comment: I followed the discussion but honestly I couldn't make a full clue out of it. According to https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/pull/1005 there should actually be org-goto support

Comment: That's if you call `counsel-org-goto`. But `org-refile` is not set up to call `counsel-org-goto`. You can request an improvement to add support for this.

Comment: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1564